# Displaying Persian dates in highchart from its corresponding Georgian date

Tags: javascript, highcharts

Can we use Gregorian dates together with a Georgian to Persian date converter script to show Persian dates in `Highchart` and `Highstock`?

Comment: im not sure what you really looking for, but last time I found this API so useful.
http://parsa.j.layershift.co.uk/index.html

Comment: @ehsun7b: I've already found solution. thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I borrowed [this](http://bahram.maravandi.info/calendar/js/persianDate.js) js script and tried it out [here](http://jsfiddle.net/larsenmtl/gv7sF/).  Not sure if that is what you are after though.

[image]

Comment: the source script "persianDate.js" is no longer available, could someone please send me a copy or post a working link here? tnx :]

Answer (score 14):

Then better way to override date formating is to use `Highcharts.dateFormats` (and [persianDate](http://babakhani.github.io/PersianWebToolkit/doc/persian-date/#display) library), This allows conversion of all dates (not x or y axis) to Persian calendar.

Sample: http://jsfiddle.net/smpaB/1/

[image: Highcharts with persian date]

Add pesianDate library with:

```
<script src="http://rawgithub.com/babakhani/PersianDate/master/dist/persian-date.min.js"></script>
```

And configure highcharts with:

```
Highcharts.dateFormats = {
    'a': function(ts){return new persianDate(ts).format('dddd')},
    'A': function(ts){return new persianDate(ts).format('dddd')},
    'd': function(ts){return new persianDate(ts).format('DD')},
    'e': function(ts){return new persianDate(ts).format('D')},
    'b': function(ts){return new persianDate(ts).format('MMMM')},
    'B': function(ts){return new persianDate(ts).format('MMMM')},
    'm': function(ts){return new persianDate(ts).format('MM')},
    'y': function(ts){return new persianDate(ts).format('YY')},
    'Y': function(ts){return new persianDate(ts).format('YYYY')},
    'W': function(ts){return new persianDate(ts).format('ww')}
};
```

Comment: seems the link to PersianDate which you mentioned is redirected or got some problem; this is the git repo anyway : https://github.com/babakhani/PersianDate

Answer (score 11):

I developed a Jalali Date library, [`JDate`](https://github.com/tahajahangir/jdate), that is compatible with original javascript `Date` class. Dates in highchart/highstock charts can be converted to Jalali by replacing `window.Date` with `JDate`. With this method all date outputs is converted to jalali calendar, **And also**, date input features (like YTD feature, or range selector) works with jalali calendar.

Demo: https://tahajahangir.github.io/jdate/jalali-highcharts-demo.html
[image: Jalali date support for highcharts]

The main part of script in above demo, is:

```
<script src="//raw.githack.com/tahajahangir/jdate/master/jdate.min.js"></script>
<script>
    window.Date = JDate;
    Highcharts.setOptions({
        lang: {
            months: ['فروردين', 'ارديبهشت', 'خرداد', 'تیر', 'مرداد', 'شهریور', 'مهر', 'آبان', 'آذر', 'دی', 'بهمن', 'اسفند'],
            shortMonths: ['فروردين', 'ارديبهشت', 'خرداد', 'تیر', 'مرداد', 'شهریور', 'مهر', 'آبان', 'آذر', 'دی', 'بهمن', 'اسفند'],
            weekdays: ["یکشنبه", "دوشنبه", "سه شنبه", "چهارشنبه", "پنج‌شنبه", "جمعه", "شنبه"]
        }
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use it [babakhani persian date js](https://github.com/babakhani/PersianDate)
for example:

---

```
xAxis: {
                    type: 'datetime',
                    labels: {
                        formatter: function () {
                            var date = new Date(this.value);
                            var pdate = persianDate(date);
                            return (pdate.pDate.year - 1300) + "/" + pdate.pDate.month;
                        }
                    }
                }
```

Answer (score 0):

Update for 2 first answer

- Mark answer: http://jsfiddle.net/xgru6nya/
- Taha Jahangir answer: http://jsfiddle.net/ab7kde83/

```html
<script src="http://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/persiandate@0.2.1/dist/persiandate.min.js"></script>

<div id="container" style="height: 400px"></div>
```

````js
var chart = new Highcharts.Chart({
    chart: {
        renderTo: 'container'
    },
    xAxis: {        
        type: 'datetime',
        labels: {
            formatter: function() {
                var someDate = new Date(this.value);
                return persianDate(someDate).format('YYYY-MMMM-D');
            }
        }
    },
    
    
    
    series: [{
        data: [29.9, 71.5, 106.4, 129.2, 144.0, 176.0, 135.6, 148.5, 216.4, 194.1, 95.6, 54.4],
        pointStart: Date.UTC(2010, 0, 1),
        pointInterval: 24 * 3600 * 1000 // one day
    }]
});```
````